# Xampp Dashboard is not working

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp, and it was working on last one day ago but today i opened xampp this error showing on localhost
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23

i searched on internet but didn't get exact answer pls provide a way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

See there might be many reasons for that problem. It seems like file or folder has been moved from the requested location. Please recheck the location of files that everything should be in place. 
Also it is possible you have changed the Document root location by default htdocs to else.

Comment: No, i didn,t change anything because after weekend today i opened it. There may be some another problem